# IBM Connections 5 custom theme not getting published to second cluster node

Tags: synchronization, themes, cluster-computing, connection

we have the following small cluster setup:

- Server 1: DMGr, Nodeagent, Connections_server1
- Server 2: Nodeagent, Connections_server2

All shared resources (including the customization dir) are on a separate file server that is linked on /opt/IBM/Connections/data/shared on both servers.

I want to customize the defaultTheme, so I copied it to /customizationDir/themes/defaultTheme/custom.css

After editing some of the styles, I stopped and started Common.ear application, then the theme customizations on the first server (where the Deployment Manager is) shows up. But not on the second server.

I tried to do a full resynchronization of the nodes, stopped and started the server, executed the LCConfigService.updateConfig("versionStamp","gmt_timestamp") script, cleared the temp directory in the WAS profile, all with no luck. The second server still shows the non-customized defaultTheme.

Any ideas what I could do?

Thank you! Daniel

Comment: did you look at the SystemOut.log or look at your httpd's log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally here's the solution:

Stopping ALL cluster nodes AND the deployment manager at the same time, then deleting the temp-Folders on ALL nodes AND the deployment manager and starting all nodes again did the trick.

Not sure why this was necessary, it shouldn't be in a cluster scenario.

Daniel